# How to get radio button Id and use the result to affect another set of radio buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, fragment

I have 4 radio buttons i.e. A, B, C and D in Fragment 1. I am using savedInstanceState to carry over the selection to Fragment 2 which has radio buttons a, b, c and d. I want to be able to have 'a' preselected if 'A' was selected, 'b' if 'B' and so on. How do I go about this.

So far I have this in Fragment 1:

```
// Storing the selection
bundle.putString("argument", frequencyGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

followed by this partial attempt in Fragment 2

```
// Search through the bundle to get the ID and preselect in Fragment 2
radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.frequency_group);
        if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("argument")){
            for (int i = 0; i <= radioGroup.getChildCount()-1 ; i++){
                String id = frequencyGroup.getChildAt(i).getId();
                if (id.equals(bundle.getString("argument"))){
                    // Somehow find the radio button with the above id
// and have it checked (need help here)
                }

            }
        }
```

I am completely lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `tag` property in radio Buttons can help you.

in both fragment `onCreate()` set tags:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= radioGroup.getChildCount()-1 ; i++){
  frequencyGroup.getChildAt(i).setTag("mRadio" + String.valueOf(i));
}
```

when passing to the second fragment use this:

```
bundle.putString("argument", frequencyGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId().getTag());
```

then in second fragment get argument for find by tag:

```
String mTag = ""
if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("argument")){
   mTag = bundle.getString("argument");
}
```

then find control and set selection:

```
RadioButton mRadio = (RadioButton)findViewWithTag(mTag);
mRadio..setChecked(true);
```

(pd. sorry for my bad english)